# How-to: AngularJS Service or other component instantitate when module loads?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, web-frontend

**Hello reader, and Angularistics,**

I was wondering about a recipe of creating a service, or a provider or any other angular component which instantly instantiates ONCE when the module loads.

E.g. I have a module called **'utils'**
I have an app module called **'myApp'** which depends on 'utils'

I have a service in utils module called **'intervalRegister'** which contains a register method for app-wide api polling stuff.

we have to use this service each time when we want to register a polling, but this service smartly stops all polling when window lost the focus - to avoid unwanted network traffic.

Currently this 'intervalRegister' is instantiated trough the 'utils' module's run method but I don't think its the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding it to the run method is OK but as alternative you could add a controller that uses your `interval` service.

That's probably better because you could also add polling related logic into that controller.

I don't know any other way of automatically starting an interval and I haven't seen one in google.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/azgho901/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['utils'])
 .controller('pollController', PollController)
 .controller('mainController', MainController);

angular.module('utils', [])
    //.run(['intervalTimer', function(intervalTimer){}])
 .service('intervalTimer', IntervalTimer)
 

function IntervalTimer($interval, $log) {
    var self = this;
    this.count = 0;
    this.pollCallbacks = [];

    this.addPoll = function(callback, scope) {
        return self.pollCallbacks.push({
            fn: callback,
            scope: scope
        });
    };

    this.timer = function() {
        self.count++;
        $log.log('hello from interval timer', self.count);
        if (self.pollCallbacks.length > 0 ){
            angular.forEach(self.pollCallbacks, function(callbackObj) {
                //console.log(callbackObj.scope);
                callbackObj.fn.call(callbackObj.scope);
            });
        }
    };
    $interval(this.timer, 1000);
}

function MainController() {
 
}

function PollController(intervalTimer, $log) {
    var vm = this;
    this.messages = '';
    this.pollCounter = 0;
    this.addPolling = function() {
        var callbackObj = {
            pollCounter: angular.copy(vm.pollCounter++),
            fn: function() {
                var msg = 'poll callback no. ' + this.pollCounter + ' called!' 
       $log.log('poll callback no. ' + this.pollCounter + ' called!');
                vm.messages += 'poll callback no. ' 
                    + this.pollCounter + ' called!' + '\r\n';
      }
        };
        
     vm.pollCounter = intervalTimer.addPoll(callbackObj.fn, callbackObj);
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="pollController as pollCtrl">
        <button ng-click="pollCtrl.addPolling()">add poll</button>active polls: {{pollCtrl.pollCounter}} <pre ng-bind="pollCtrl.messages"></pre>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This logic was the first I've tried. My problem with this:
The service is not instantiated right after when the module did.
The controllers have to register only a callback - the function what have to be ran - with a parameter - the repeating time.
But this way when the controller destroyed ( like when leaving route )  the intervalled stuff will be unavailable. Altough in the register service I'd deal with the logic when the window is not focused I'd wont run those callbacks, but leave them in the registered stuff.

p.s.: thanks for ur reply